# Track changes with in pdf documents for non-Latex reviewers

Tags: pdf, latex, microsoft-word

Background: I'm one of the very few people using LaTeX in my university. And every time I'm stage where I present a first draft to my professors I'm faced with the same problem. They are used to students handing in MS Word files that has some excellent track changing capabilities, which are lacking in a pdf file.

I've looked into two ways to enable track changes when working with LaTeX:

- Online subscriptions like ShareLaTeX, Overleaf or Papeeria: These are great when you are collaborating with other LaTeX users, but not so much when asking for a extensive feedback from a non-LaTeX user
- latex2rtf or pandoc to generate a rtf/doc/docx file that my professors can edit: The documents end up being formatted so horribly, that the professor would need to work in two documents at once. Reading in the pdf and editing in the docx. This is impractical and too much to ask for

Now to my question: **Is there a browser based method to enable track changes in the pdf file similar to the features within Microsoft Word?**

The main feature which pdf readers lack is being able to directly change the text resulting in <s>something like this</s>*tracked, visible changes. Comments don't suffice!*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xodo Connect](https://www.xodo.com/app/#/) allows for collaboration on any document, including PDF. It is completely web based, with no need for registration or plugin installs.

1. Simply go to [Xodo](https://www.xodo.com/app/#/)
2. Upload your file
3. Open the file
4. Select the "Person with Plus Symbol" on the top tool bar, and you can invite
   anybody to collaborate on the document.

They can then view immediately, no sign in or install required for any browser.

Comment: it doesn't have all features that I'm looking for, but it is pretty amazing none the less. Thank you!